# Notice errors in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I am working on a PHP website project. The website runs fine. But I am getting Notice Errors like this:

Notice: Undefined index: process in C:\xampp\htdocs\myphpproject\index.php on line 9

Now this is Line 9 in the index.php:

```
if($_POST['process']=='true') {few if statements and SQL queries are here}
```

Eventhough my website works fine but I have a lot of these notice errors. What is the problem in the above code and how can I avoid the mistakes that cause these kind of notice errors?

P.S. I already know that I can hide them but I prefer to fix them instead of hiding them :)

Thank you

Comment: Since it's marked dupe by John, I cannot post an answer. But here's the answer: Change your if to: `if (isset($_POST['process']) && $_POST['process'] == true) { //stuff }`

Comment: Thank you @matrixdevuk. I used your comments and it works :)

Comment: There is a rating button next to my comment if you hover over it, press that if you want. @MaryJane

Comment: @matrixdevuk, as I see there is no button next to your comment. Or maybe there is and I can not find it. Sorry, new user :)